# Printing php variables

Tags: php

Hello Everyone I am doing some coding in php i want to print php variable with error message i tried so many methods but its not working,. CAn anubody give suggestion how to solve this
Here is my code

```
$job_validate_demux_type = $this->validate_possible_value($gstaf_format_demux["demux_format"],explode(",",$validate_array[38]));

        if($job_validate_demux_type == "empty")
        {
            array_push($gstaf_format_demux_array,"Demux Format is empty");
        }
        else if($job_validate_demux_type == "invalid")
        {
            array_push($gstaf_format_demux_array,"Demux Format value is invalid ");
        }
```

I am doing some validation i need to print the value of php variable with error message
for ex: `array_push($gstaf_format_demux_array,"Demux Format value is invalid ");` i need to print `$gstaf_format_demux["demux_format"]` value with error message.Please help me to solve this

Comment: why is printing the values from that array a problem? (you should just loop over them, and print their contents with `print()` or `echo`), and what does javascript have to do with this?

Comment: i have so many blocks and so many error messages so  i am pushing all error messages to array

Comment: i can see that, and there isn't anything wrong with that practice.

Comment: from what i figure, you want to do this : `for($i=0; $i<$gstaf_format_demux_array;$i++) print($gstaf_format_demux_array[i] . "\n");`

Comment: Nothing wrong in that but what i need is i need to print the value of $gstaf_format_demux["demux_format"] this with "Demux Format is empty"

Comment: i can't tell how you are populating the arrays from the code you pasted, it would help to know what should be in the arrays, and if it gets there at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use `echo`, `print_r` or `var_dump`;

**Echo** command printing only strings. (cannot convert array to string)

**Print_r** command printing strings and arrays (recursive).

**Var_dump** command printing string and arrays. (with variable type)

I think the best way for this code will be `echo`, because you wan't print string.

Example:

`echo "Demux Format is empty\n"`

`foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo "$error[message]\n";
}`

**\n** is new line